# jquery validate errorPlacement in select2.js

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, jquery-select2

When error replacement in `select2` is showing up above the box, I want the error replacement below the box. Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="form" class="form_required">
    <select type="text" id="test1" class="form-control select2" required>
        <option value="">&nbsp();</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="insert()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
$('.select2').select2()

$(".form_required").validate({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-control').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');     
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-control').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
        else if (element.prop('type') === 'radio' && element.parent('.radio-inline').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent().parent());
        }
        else if (element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().parent());
        }
        else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});

function insert(){
    if ($('#form').valid()){
        alert('OK');
    }
}
```

1) [image] 2) [image]

When not using `select2` the error replacement is showing up below box the like number 2 but when using `select2` error replacement is showing up above the box..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5f0r9vsy/86/ this example

Comment: Integrating jQuery Validate with Select2 has been asked and answered before.  Please use the search.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you check the source code of the [select2](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.js) library, you'll see that the `select2-container` (container responsible for the select2 dropdown) is inserted right after the `select` element. Here's the part of the code which does that:

```
Select2.prototype._placeContainer = function ($container) {
 $container.insertAfter(this.$element);

 var width = this._resolveWidth(this.$element, this.options.get('width'));

 if (width != null) {
  $container.css('width', width);
 }
};
```

which gets us to easily place the **error message** from the jquery-validate after this `select2-container`. Here's the change in the `errorPlacement` option:

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if(element.hasClass('select2') && element.next('.select2-container').length) {
        error.insertAfter(element.next('.select2-container'));
    }
    ....
```

And a snippet showing the results:

```js
$('.select2').select2({container: 'body'})

$(".form_required").validate({
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-control').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');     
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.form-control').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      if(element.hasClass('select2') && element.next('.select2-container').length) {
         error.insertAfter(element.next('.select2-container'));
        } else if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
        else if (element.prop('type') === 'radio' && element.parent('.radio-inline').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent().parent());
        }
        else if (element.prop('type') === 'checkbox' || element.prop('type') === 'radio') {
            error.appendTo(element.parent().parent());
        }
        else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
form {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="form" class="form_required form-horizontal">    

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-8">

    <select type="text" id="test1" class="form-control select2" required>
        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
        <option value="1">test1</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" onclick="insert()">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>

<form id="form2" class="form_required form-horizontal">    

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <select type="text" id="test2" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
        <option value="1">test2</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" onclick="insert2()">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>

<script>
function insert(){
    if ($('#form').valid()){
        alert('OK');
    }
}

function insert2(){
    if ($('#form2').valid()){
        alert('OK');
    }
}
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much @Shashank

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: helped me a lot. thanks

Comment: Thanks for help just want to give what i have to change in the code : I was not able to find the same class may be due to come changes so i did : "select2-hidden-accessible"  
            if(element.hasClass('select2-hidden-accessible') && element.next('.select2-container').length) {
                error.insertAfter(element.next('.select2-container'));
            }